# What type of video format is compatible with iPad to be embedded on the app? (Converted from SWF)

Tags: ipad, video, flash

I am developing an app on iPad. One type of our data is flash (**swf**) files. I wonder what type of video format is the best to **convert** these flash files to, considering that the converted ones should be **embedded on the app** itself.

Thanks,
Sara

Answer (score 1):

[H.264](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC) is standard de-facto nowadays, not only for iPad but for all other platforms too.